# Migrating Users along with their password

Tags: users, migration

I would like to migrate users from one wordpress site to another along with their paasswords, there are 15000 users in total . what would be the best way to do this . is a migration of the database tables wp_users and wp_user_meta recommended ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like importing tables would be easier. Do your new site already have users (apart from admin users)?

Comment: no users in the target site apart from admin.

Comment: I have imported the users and the user meta tables and it works great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the 2 tables in the target database and faced permission issue while logging in to the target site , then I followed this site http://beconfused.com/2007/how-to-solve-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-in-wordpress/ and it fixed the issue.